# Accessing TFS and VSO from abroad?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm planning on travelling the world next month and I would like to know if I will have any problems accessing TFS online or VS online while I'm travelling?
Countries I'm planning on visiting: Thailand, Vietnam, Philippines, and some countries in Europe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with that. I know that a lot of people in Europe and Asia are using VS online.